# Restrict user to enter certain characters in `input` field

Tags: angular

How to prevent the user from entering '#' character into an `input` field?

I'm struggling to accomplish it.

Comment: i have an input field and i want to restrict user so that he/she can not enter # into input field .

Comment: @sonu you can use [patterns](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp).

Comment: not working already tried.

Comment: You can insert the char '#', but he can't submit it. As @Sakuto said you should put more information.

Comment: Why is this closed? It's completely valid question: how to PREVENT user from typing some characters. Let's go ahead and vote for re-opening it! Also, not sure why this one has downvoted dso many time...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be to make a directive which will filter the things, so nothing will enter in the model binding part of the app because they wont be able to enter anything.. below is an example directive for your case

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[inputFilter]'
})
export class inputFilterDirective {



    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }


    @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event) {
        let e = <KeyboardEvent> event;

        if (e.keyCode == 35) {
           e.preventDefault();
        } else {
           return;
        }

    }
}
```

I had it done for numbers only, so the users couldnt enter anything else besides numbers, but I modified it for hashtag => the hashtag has a keyCode of 35.

You use the directive like this `<input inputFilter [(ngModel)]="whatever"/>`

Comment: @sonu is there any regax expression to restrict characters to enter